# Could not allocate required memory for image

Tags: qgis, raster, export, image, dpi

I'm trying to export a 24k image (export set to 1650DPI) using the "export as image" function but I keep getting the "Could not allocate required memory for image" warning.

I don't understand why this is happening as I am running 64bit and have 64gb of RAM installed.

Exporting at a slightly lower DPI of 1400 works and produces a file that is only 50mb. I've checked resource usage and I don't even break the 32gb mark so how can QGIS be running out of memory!?

Comment: Is the *application* 32-bit or 64-bit? If it's the former, you're not likely able to exceed 1Gb.

Comment: If your on a windows pc, then it could be assisted with more virtual memory. The QGIS windows service could be paging or hanging when trying to export such a large file. Under environmental variables you can up the virtual memory.

Comment: @Vince The application is 64bit, unless the installer is bugged. 

How can it be hitting memory limitations when I'm watching RAM readouts and not seeing it go above 32gb? Some of the outputs at 1400dpi are only 4mb!

Comment: Have the same issue but my source layer is actually a XYZ tile layer (served as raster). Believe there are other factors at play as I'm already using 64-bit version with plenty of system memory...